# Matlab Frangi Filter Enhanced Unwanted Objects

Tags: matlab

I was using [Matlab version Frangi filter](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter) to enhance long and thin brighter blobs for my current project. It works well for heterogeneous data. However, I got a lot of unwanted objects when applying on the controlled homogeneous data. Most of them are not long and thin features I was looking for ideas to control the eccentricity of the filter.

Here are the code I have

```
Img = imread('test.png');
Img = im2double(Img);
options = struct('FrangiScaleRange', [5 7], 'FrangiScaleRatio', 2, 'FrangiBetaOne', 0.5, 'FrangiBetaTwo', 15, 'verbose',true,'BlackWhite',true);
[IEnhance,~]=FrangiFilter2D(1-Img,options);
IEnhance = mat2gray(IEnhance);
imshow(IEnhance)
```

I tried to not scale the data but the output of blank and detection data have similar response intensity.

Comment: Did you try changing `FrangiScaleRatio`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your reply. I agree with you change ScaleRatio could work for blank data but since the thickness of my target lies in this range also, it will also fail to pick up the target.

Comment: I suggested that because you seem to be "looking for ideas to control the eccentricity of the filter." The `FrangiScaleRatio` does just that.

Comment: It would be good if you attached an example image with the things you are trying to detect. For this one example image, you want `zeros(size(Img))` as output, but that is not a general solution.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think this is just a `mat2gray` auto-scale problem

Comment: @AnderBiguri: you might every well be right. I would still like to see an image *with* the stuff to be detected.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hello, Thanks! I attached the image contains stuff to be detected (you can visually see the lines on the image)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is caused by `mat2gray`.

I assume the filter outputs different numerical values dependent on the image, however, when you call `mat2gray`, you are autoscaling to `min(IEnhance)` and `max(IEnhance)`.

The FEX comes with an image. If we run

```
Img = imread('vessel.png');
Img = im2double(Img); % autoscale input, 
options = struct('FrangiScaleRange', [5 7], 'FrangiScaleRatio', 2, 'FrangiBetaOne', 0.5, 'FrangiBetaTwo', 15, 'verbose',true,'BlackWhite',true);
[IEnhance,~]=FrangiFilter2D(Img,options);

imshow(IEnhance,[])
colorbar
```

[image]

We can see that the scale goes to about 3*10^-5.

Instead, if we run your image as:

```
Img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlNeb.png');
Img = im2double(Img);
options = struct('FrangiScaleRange', [5 7], 'FrangiScaleRatio', 2, 'FrangiBetaOne', 0.5, 'FrangiBetaTwo', 15, 'verbose',true,'BlackWhite',true);
[IEnhance2,~]=FrangiFilter2D(Img,options);

imshow(IEnhance2,[])
colorbar
```

[image]

In this case the scale goes to 3*10^6

If we plot them at the same scale:

```
subplot(121)
imshow(IEnhance,[0 3e-5])
subplot(122)
imshow(IEnhance2,[0 3e-5])
```

[image]

You can see now that the result of the filter is correct, as it is detecting the random noise as background as random noise almost. Note that we can do this because we are indeed auto-scaling the input (`im2double`) and that the input images are of the same scale. This is a non-important assumption for single applications as most devices will output images in the same scale, but in the hypothetical case of them not being the same scale, the interpretation of the different values of the output would not be as comparable.

Lesson to learn: 
The output of the filter is probability, do not autoscale probabilities!

---

Note in my demos I have modified the call to the filder to just call Img, as that is how the FEX file works. You probably have your reasons to invert it.

Comment: Thanks Ander! I was also thinking the problem is causing by scaling issue. However, if using no scaling frangi output, the case that should be detected also very dark. I attached the image so you can try it out.

Comment: @SimaGuanxing those images have different resolution, and possibly different real-life pixel size, that can have an impact. Can you post two same -sized images, or is this not the case of your application?

Comment: The reason I invert the image is because my detection stuffs are brighter than neighbors

Comment: They are scanned using the same device but since the sample is in different size, I have to rotate and find the max rectangle area to use frangi. That's why the cropped data are in different size.

Comment: @SimaGuanxing then there is the chance that my answer is just wrong, unfortunately. A thing that you can do is once you get the result, to try and measure the size of the white blobs you get. If they are long, they are feature, otherwise they are noise